# Perform selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I can't figure out why the code in if statement is not executed

```
 NSString *str = @"capitalizedString";
    NSString *name = @"chris";

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(str);

    if([NSString respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [name performSelector:selector]);
    }
```

EDIT //
This code works fine

```
NSString *color = @"blueColor";
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(color); 
    if([UIColor respondsToSelector:selector])
    {
        myColor = [UIColor performSelector:selector];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`capitalizedString` is not a static method. So you can not use NSString directly. Instead you should use the object of it. In your case it could ne name or str.

Comment: So in this scenario. performSelector can be applied only for class methods ?

Comment: No it can be applied to both instance method and static methods. But capitalizedString is an instance method, you should use [name respondsToSelector:selector].

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
if ([name respondsToSelector:selector])
```

or

```
if ([NSString instancesRespondToSelector:selector])
```

The way you have it now, you're asking if the class object itself responds to the method, which it doesn't.

Comment: Some docs for that [NSObject Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
if([NSString respondsToSelector:@selector(capitalizedString)]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [name @selector(capitalizedString)]);
    }
```